# Connect to mongodb on heroku using native drivers in express node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, express

On my local machine i connect to mongoDb "tasksdb" database this way:

```
var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true, });
db = new Db('tasksdb', server);

db.open(function(err, db) {
if(!err) {
   console.log("Connected to 'tasksdb' database");
   db.collection('tasks', {safe:true}, function(err, collection) {
if (err) {
   console.log("The 'tasks' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with sample data...");
   populateDB();
  }
 });
 }
});
```

how to force it to work on heroku ? I tried:

```
var server = new Server(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI, process.env.PORT, {auto_reconnect: true, });
db = new Db('heroku_mydatabase', server);
```

but it doesn't work. On each example in web people use "connect" but i want to do it this way. Is it possible ?

Comment: You are taking the wrong port. You need to take the port of the MongoLab URI, not the port of your Heroku environment.

MONGOLAB_URI is the whole URI, you need to take only the host.
So, split MONGOLAB_URI, take the host and port separately and pass it into the function.

Comment: I tried var server = new Server("mongodb://xxx:yyy@ds033709.mongolab.com/clients", 33709, {auto_reconnect: true}); but no luck